# Обработка кликов в Grid

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, существует ли способ получить адрес (столбец и строку) ячейки в контроле Grid, по которой был осуществлен клик мышкой, не задавая обработчик события для каждой ячейки?
То есть я хочу обрабатывать клик по самому Grid, а не по ячейке.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, существует.

1. Можно при клике на Grid вычитать по очереди из координаты мыши во время клика ширину столбцов (если они одинаковые, можно и разделить) и сравнивать с нулём. На какой итерации станет меньше нуля, тот и номер ячейки в строке. Номер строки получается аналогично, только вычитать/делить на высоту одной строки.
2. Можно посмотреть наличие свойства SelectedItem или ему подобного.
3. Если вы можете назначить обработчик на каждую ячейку, то можете назначить один обработчик для всех ячеек, а доступ к данным конкретной ячейки - через sender. =) Самый простой вариант, мне кажется, если обработчик одинаковый для всех.